# Why my .exe file just gives me an error with Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert my `.pyw` into a `.exe` with `pyinstaller` but always gives me an error. But I try to convert the shortest version of the code, it works. What should I do?

It has dependencies with one folder of images, but even after putting the folder in the same directory of the `.exe`, it fails.
The shortest version of the code is:

```py
from tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox

messagebox.showinfo("Hello World", "Hello World")

root=Tk()
root2=Tk()
root3=Tk()

myFrame=Frame()
myFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

disc=Canvas(root, bg="black", width="600", height="600", bd=-1)

def _create_circle(self, x, y, r, **kwargs):
    return self.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)

Canvas.create_circle = _create_circle

disc.create_circle(300, 300, 300, fill="white", outline="")

root.title("Geometria Hiperbòlica")
root.iconbitmap("Imatges\\Disc_de_Poincaré.ico")
root.resizable(0,0)

root2.title("Resultats")
root2.iconbitmap("Imatges\\Disc_de_Poincaré.ico")
root2.config(width=300, height=100)
root2.resizable(0,0)
root2.config(bd=20, relief="sunken", bg="grey")

root3.title("Instruccions")
root3.iconbitmap("Imatges\\Disc_de_Poincaré.ico")
root3.config(width=300, height=100)
root3.resizable(0,0)
root3.config(bd=20, relief="sunken", bg="grey")
myFrame.config(bg="grey")
disc.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I also don't know how to see what causes the error, so if needed I could post the full code.
Thanks.

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: Failed to execute script

Comment: Try to use hard coded paths for images e.g  for "Imatges\\Disc_de_Poincaré.ico" user full path to "Disc_de_Poincaré.ico" file

Comment: Thanks, now I try it.

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: can you try showing some log. may be a hello world screen. Just put the code into it. check this link on how to do it https://pythonspot.com/tk-message-box/

Comment: you mean this? Now what?